# Signed int in c language assignd bitfields but confusion

Tags: c, bit-fields, signed-integer

Currently I am working on c and facing a confusion regarding signed int in structure and here I have given the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct {
  signed int age : 4;
} Age;

int main( ) {

   Age.age = -8;
   printf("Age.age : %d\n", Age.age );

   return 0;
}
```

Here, I already have described the size of bits which int will occupy while storing the value. here I am assigning value -8 to age. so it will store value like 1000 for 8 and for -8 it should store like 11000 where left 1st bit is known as sign bit. So if int age have to store -8 it must have 5 bits but while I compile the given example it is not giving error and displays an output.

Please help me with my issues.

Comment: Why do you need signed? bitfields is easier with unsigned.

Comment: i want to understand the internal working of this issue.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh its for my understanding.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) answer .. signed values use 2's complement. 4 bits gives a range of `-8`-`7` .. For example, what output do you get when you do `Age.age = 8` ..?

Comment: So here's about signed bitfields: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4590032/2079103

Comment: Your architecture is most likely using two's complement for number representation.  For 4 bits then, the max signed integer is 0111 = 7 decimal, and the smallest is 1000 = -8 decimal.  So with two's complement representation -8 fits in the four bits.

Comment: See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, integers are stored using [2's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) representation on your system.

In 2's complement, a 4-bit bitfield can hold a range of `-8` through to `+7`.  The bit representation `1000` will mean `-8`, and it is not possible to store `+8`.

Assigning an out-of-range value (such as `+8` in this case) causes implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: I just gave you 2 compliments.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation in very short  term.

Comment: Good understanding